# android - set intent extra from inside runnable

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm still new to android development. I've been at this problem for some time but am still unable to figure out what to do on my own. In an Activity I set up a series of Runnables containing CountDownTimers. One executes after the next, but depending on which CountDownTimer is active, I need to pass a different Intent.extra to a fragment. I've tried setting my extra from inside Runnable, inside Run, and inside of the CountDownTimer onTick, and onFinish.

I fear I have way too much going on in my original Activity to post it, but here is the problem in essence.

```
public class MatchUpActivity extends Activity implements OpponentFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

List mTotalDrafts;
Bundle mBundle; 

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_up);

     mBundle = new Bundle();
     mDraftUsernames = extras.getStringArrayList("DRAFT_LIST");

       for (int i = 0; i < totalDrafts; i++) {

            Handler delayhandler = new Handler();

            delayhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            //bundle.put("extra", totalDrafts.get(0))

                public void run() {

                            //bundle.put("extra", totalDrafts.get(0))

                    getTimer();

                }

            }, mTodaysDraftTime + (i * singleDraftDuration) - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

        }
   }
```

CountDownTimer

```
  private void getTimer() {
    new CountDownTimer(singleDraftDuration, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                            //bundle.put("extra", totalDrafts.get(0))

        }
        public void onFinish() {

                            //bundle.put("extra", totalDrafts.get(0))

                   list.remove(0)
            }

    }.start();
}
```

}

I am able to remove items from my list in onFinish, but after I do so I need to send the next element in the list as an extra.

I hope this is enough code to get my question across. I tried to change some things from my original code for simplicity. If there is something I am missing or a better way to do this, please, anybody let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Define the Bundle as global variable in your Activity and not in a Method implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I fear I misrepresented my code problem slightly. I do have Bundle defined in the global scope. I changed my above code to more closely reflect what I have. However, do you know for sure that this should work? Runnable works on the main UI thread, correct?